# Can I set the default behavior for my app to not show notifications in notification center?

Tags: cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I want to take advantage of NSUserNotification in Mac OS 10.8 Mountain Lion to display a nice notification to the user of my app, but I don't want to have this particular notification stored in the Notification Center on the upper right of the ML desktop. I know the user can go into System Preferences and change the notification behavior for my app to not show it in Notification Center, but is there a way to set that by default, or to clear all notifications out of the Notification Center?

My notification code looks like this:

```
    NSUserNotificationCenter *nc = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];
    notification.informativeText=@"text";
    notification.subtitle=[";
    [nc deliverNotification:notification];
```

Thanks!

Comment: It seems I can just call     [nc removeAllDeliveredNotifications]; where nc is my NSUserNotificationCenter. Is that the best way to do it or is there a way to just not put the notifications in the Notification Center to begin with?

Comment: I don't think there is any other (Apple-approved) way than to first deliver the notication and then to remove it after some seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for your application to achieve the equivalent of going into NotificationCenter and setting your alert style to 'None', there's a info.plist setting that's supposed to do this. It's called
NSUserNotificationAlertStyle

The documentation isn't very clear, but I believe the valid values are: none, banners, and alerts

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW1